# Чем отличается архитектура ПО и дизайн ПО?

Tags: архитектура, дизайн

Архитектура - более высокоуровневое понятие, чем дизайн?

Comment: Все ниже сказанное - личное мнение: на мой взгляд, эти понятия сходны с понятиями архитектуры и дизайна применительно к, например, зданиям. И грань между ними весьма размыта. А вообще, например, [здесь](http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openupru/openup_basic/guidances/concepts/software_architecture,__O7tAMVvEduLYZUGfgZrkQ.html) говорится, что дизайн более общее понятие, а архитектура - лишь один из аспектов дизайна.

Answer (score 1):

Есть книга "Информационная архитектура" в которой даже описана возможная будущая специальность - информационный архитектор. Если кратко, информационная архитектура это структура информации. А дизайн это более общее понятие.